# Purple Noise Modeling / Differentiated White Noise (Kalman Filtering)

Tags: noise, kalman-filters

I am designing a Kalman Filter for a signal which features a certain kind of noise and I do not know how to model it properly in the filter.
The noise is constructed from a white noise source, called $w(t)$
by taking the difference of the current noise-sample and the last noise sample ($\Delta t$ is the sample-time):

$\eta(t) = w(t) - w(t-\Delta t)$

From my current point of view this is basically high-pass filtered noise or some kind of differentiated white noise (I read purple noise somewhere) with a sinusiodal power spectral density.

Question 1:
Do you agree on my thoughts above?

Question 2:
How can this noise be modeled in terms of a Kalman Filter?
Would a Markov-model be suitable? How to express the color of this noise in a Kalman Filter?

Regards

Comment: Purple noise increases with frequency, not a sinusoidal PSD...

Comment: Kalman filter assumes white noise. You can get around this by augmenting your state vector. The new state represents the output of your coloring filter due to a white input.

Comment: @CMDoolittle Within the nyquist frequency I can do a taylor series of the exact $sin^2$ PSD which eventually leads to a PSD proportional to $f^2$. Hence this is violet noise. Am I correct that a Gauss-Markov model can only be used for colored noise which has a low-pass frequency behavior, i.e. I cannot use it?

Comment: @DavidWurtz I know that white noise is assumed, however this only depends on the modeling as you mentioned. Also brown noise is easily modeled using augmentation. The thing is I have never seen a Kalman Filter which works on differentiated white noise. Is this even possible?

Comment: The differentiation you refer to is a FIR filter. This fits within the state space framework no problem. For example, you could define 3 states: a(t) = b(t-1), b(t) = w(t), and c(t) = b(t-1) - a(t-1), where w(t) is your white noise source. Now c(t) is differencing the white noise source.

Comment: I still have a lot of questions on my mind... 1) Can this violet noise be incorporated in a Kalman Filter? 2) Am I correct that a Markov-model cannot be used for it since a Markov-Model is basically low-pass filtered noise? c) I need a continuous state-space model (which is why I wrote $t-\Delta t$ and not $t_{k-1}$.  Is there a common noise model (like Gauss-Markov) to model high-pass noise?